# VBA Advanced Filter Runtime error 5 Invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: vba

New to VBA, would really appreciate some pointers on this error when trying to advanced filter a table into another table on a different sheet.

```
Sub GenerateExceptionsList()

Dim Commissioning_Table As ListObject
Dim ExceptionsList_Table As ListObject
Dim ExceptionsCriteria_Table As ListObject

    Set Commissioning_Table = Sheets("CommissioningData").ListObjects("CommissioningTable")
    Set ExceptionsList_Table = Sheets("Exceptions List").ListObjects("ExceptionsList_Table")
    Set ExceptionsCriteria_Table = Sheets("Exceptions Tables").ListObjects("ExceptionsCriteria_Table")

Commissioning_Table.DataBodyRange.AdvancedFilter (xlFilterCopy), ExceptionsCriteria_Table, ExceptionsList_Table.DataBodyRange, False


End Sub
```

Get the error:

> Runtime error 5, Invalid Procedure call or argument

Comment: What you're trying to do is hard to understand, because "advanced filter a table *into another table*" makes no sense at all. What are you trying to do? FWIW you're getting that error specifically because the ranges you're supplying aren't in the same table.

Comment: Just to be clear: your question is unanswerable until you [edit] it to clarify what you mean to be doing.